# Area of plane $2x+y+2z=2$ in the cylinder $x^2+y^2=16$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

Area of plane $2x+y+2z=16$ in the cylinder $x^2+y^2=16$ I'm having trouble making sure I'm getting the correct answer so I'll walk through it and hopefully someone can point out if it is correct.

$$2x+y+2z=16 \rightarrow z=8-x-{y\over2}$$
$$A(s)={\int \int}_D \sqrt{1+({\partial z\over \partial x})^2+({\partial z\over \partial y})^2}={\int \int}_D \sqrt{9\over4}dA={3\over2}{\int \int}_DdA$$
Then I transform into cylindrical:
$${3\over2} { {\int_0^{2\pi}} {\int_0^4} rdrd\theta}=24\pi$$
I think the biggest problem I'm having justifying this is that I'm not sure I can go to cylindrical cordanites where I did, is that valid? Is the answer correct?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why even go to polar? It's just the area of a circle.

Comment: @ZacharySelk $A={\pi}r^2=16{\pi}$ Is the answer? I don't quite understand how it's just the area of a circle. When the plane cuts the cylinder flat, but then at a steeper angle won't there be more area in the steeper angle cut?

Comment: You're not integrating over the circle floating above, but the shadow in the XY plane which is just a plane (get it?) ol circle.

Comment: @ZacharySelk How would you do this using calculus though? is there a way?

Comment: Just like you did.

Comment: @ZacharySelk ? I have two different answers then: $16{\pi}$ and $24{\pi}$

Comment: Well $16\pi \times 3/2$ is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $dS$ is a constant so your integral is simply the area of the circle time $dS$

$$A= \int \int _D dS = \int \int _D 3/2 dA = 3/2(16\pi ) = 24\pi $$